# Removing session with key starting with specific characters

Tags: php, session, loops

How can i remove, unset session variables starting with key pattern like

Where keys like

```
Guard_1660743344
Guard_4323340344
Guard_5343332233
.....
Guard_[dynamicvalue]
```

I want to remove all session variables from tray if session key started with "Guard_"

```
unset($_SESSION[$key]);
```

Sorry i tried my best to find solution but failed, therefore asked

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess a `foreach` loop will be the best in this case: (**[Working eval.in](https://eval.in/47828)**)

```
<?php 

    foreach(array_keys($_SESSION) as $key) // loop over all keys of the session
        if(substr($key,0,6)=='Guard_') // if the key starts with Guard_
            unset($_SESSION[$key]); // unset it

?>
```

Note that looping on `array_keys($_SESSION)` will be more efficient than looping the entire `$_SESSION` array..

Comment: @Boaz You are right, however for efficiency measures I've changed it to loop over `array_keys($_SESSION)`.. so in that case `as $key` is fine :)

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple to do:

```
foreach($_SESSION as $key => $value) { //iterate over all session keys
    if(substr($key, 0, 6) === 'Guard_') { //test if the key prefix matches
        unset($_SESSION[$key]); //if it does, remove it from the array
    }
}
```